# Mysql operational error (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I need to connect Mysql database to FastAPI. Mysql uses custom port (17001). Also I need use docker-compose.

Database:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

DB_USER = 'api'
DB_PASSWORD = 'test'
DB_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
DATABASE = 'main'
DB_PORT = 17001

connect_uri = f'mysql+pymysql://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_HOST}:{DB_PORT}/{DATABASE}'

engine = create_engine(connect_uri)
Base = declarative_base()

from . import Models

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

Docker-compose:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  database:
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "main"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "test"
      MYSQL_USER: "api"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "test"
      MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 17001
    ports:
      - "17001:17001"
    volumes:
      - ./MySQLData:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - main
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:17001"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10
  api:
    restart: on-failure
    build:
      dockerfile: ./api/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./api
        target: /app
    ports:
      - 17002:17002
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - main

networks:
  main:
```

`./api/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR /code
COPY ./api/requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt
COPY ./api /code/app
CMD ["python3", "/code/app/Main.py"]
```

When I am running this using `docker compose up`, I gets this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
```

When I am running MySQL using docker compose, then I am running api by hand, all works fine.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: can you try `DB_HOST = 'database`?

Comment: @python_user, I tried this, but it has no result

Comment: did you get a different error?

Comment: @python_user, No, I didn't

Comment: did you build again? `docker compose up --build` after the DB_HOST change?

Comment: The DB HOST is set to 127.0.0.1, which wont work unless you have the app and mysql running in the same container. Might try setting DB_HOST to point to the db service name in your compose file

Comment: @AndrewNolan, Should I write something like this: 
`environment:
      DB_HOST: .`
?

Comment: It is not recommended to use hard-coded configuration values in code(the db configurations), instead you can load it from environment variable. As it will provide a good way to set application execution parameters (whoever wants to run your application, simply set the required env vars and start.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have forgotten about --build. To run, I uses `docker compose up --build`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).